# Sampling from a given density

Tags: random-variable, density-function

Let X be a random variable with this density function

$f_X(x)$ = 6x(1 - x) * $1_{[0,1]}(x)$

Problem: Run the random experiment to get a value of X.

I feel this is a very easy problem, but I do not entirely understand the $1_{[0,1]}(x)$ of the equation. Am I merely picking a value for x between [0,1] and plugging it into the equation above to get a value for X or am I missing the mark?

Comment: Hint: take the middle value of three independent random values uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$.  For instance, an `R` command to do this would be `X <- median(runif(3))`.

Comment: The question is "how can you build a procedure that generates samples from that target distribution". The basic sampling procedure is sampling from the uniform distribution. Can you transform it into your target ?

Comment: And for your notation question : that the function with value 1 for x between 0 and 1 and 0 elsewhere. Your target is a random variable that is bounded

Comment: The *question* at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173637 contains an answer, because the distribution it discusses is that of $f_{2X-1}$, which is easily related to $f_X$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple thing to fix, so no worries! The $1_{[0,1]}(x)$ is merely an *indicator* function.  Remember that the area under the density function must integrate to 1.  If you graphed $f_X(x)$ without the indicator on a graph, the area wouldn't integrate to 1.  The area would, however, integrate to one if you restricted the function on the interval $[0,1].$

The indicator function $1_{[a,b]}(x)$ equals 1 on $[a,b]$ and equals 0 everywhere else (that is, outside $[a,b]$).  The function $f_X(x)$ includes the indicator function $1_{[0,1]}(x)$ so that $6x(1-x)$ is nonzero only on the interval $[0,1]$ and is zero everywhere else.

In order to sample from that density, you need to only generate a random number from that density and discard any number outside of $[0,1].$  There's likely an easy way to accomplish this in your software of choice, but I hope this helps to get you started!

Comment: To nitpick a little, $6x(1-x)$ is nonzero on $(0,1)$ but has value $0$ if $x=0$ or $1$. More to the point, $6x(1-x)$ is nonzero _everywhere_ except at $0$ and $1$; it is $f_X(x) = 6x(1-x)\mathbf 1_{[0,1]}(x)$ that is guaranteed to be $0$ for  $x \notin [0,1]$.