# Generating samples from kernels other than Epanechnikov's

Tags: random-generation, kernel-smoothing

Generating samples from kernel densities with Gaussian kernel [is very simple](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43674/simple-sampling-method-for-a-kernel-density-estimator), the same with uniform, or triangular kernels. There is also a smart algorithm for [generating samples from Epanchenikov kernel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173637/generating-a-sample-from-epanechnikovs-kernel), however is it possible to generate samples from other kernels (e.g. [biweight, cosine, optcosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29)) in more efficient way than by using than accept-reject algorithm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the inverse cdf method. For the biweight kernel,
$$
\begin{align}F(x)&=\int_{-1}^x \frac{15}{16}(1-u^2)^2\text{d}u\\ &= \int_{-1}^x \frac{15}{16}(1-2u^2+u^4)\text{d}u\\
&=\frac{15}{16}\left\{ x+1-2\frac{x^3+1}{3}+\frac{x^5+1}{5}\right\}\\\end{align}
$$
which can be inverted numerically, while, for the cosine kernel,
$$
\begin{align}F(x)&=\int_{-1}^x \frac{\pi}{4}\cos(\pi u/2)\text{d}u\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\{\sin(\pi x/2)+1\}\end{align}$$
which produces
$$F^{-1}(u)=2\arcsin(2u-1)/\pi$$
Note that the biweight cdf looks very similar to the logistic cdf
$$G(x)=\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\{-4x^2+3\text{sign}(x)x^2/2\}}$$which helps with the inversion:
[image]

Comment: +1 This is a general answer because most kernels are developed to have mathematically tractable expressions for their PDFs and CDFs.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is maybe as much a question related to Xi'an's +1 answer.

I took up the idea of numerically inverting the biweight cdf, using this code:

```
library(MASS)

inverse  <-  function (f, lower = -1, upper = 1) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1]
}

biweight_inverse <- inverse(function (x) (abs(x)<=1)*15/16*(x+1-2*(x^3+1)/3+(x^5+1)/5))

reps <- 1e6
biweight_realizations <- matrix(NA,reps)
for (i in 1:reps){
  biweight_realizations[i] <- biweight_inverse(runif(1))$root  
}
truehist(biweight_realizations)
```

Sure enough, it works:

[image]

I however suspect that OP wants to avoid rejection sampling for efficiency considerations. Now, my code is awfully slow in view of the need to perform numerical inversion.

So I wonder whether (a) the inverse cdf method is really a good idea when the quantile function needs to be found numerically or (b) my code is just bad. (I am sure the loop could be avoided, but I doubt this is what slows down the simulation.)

Comment: I believe you can use `rbeta` to speed this up considerably.  The parameters are $3$ and $3$.  Just double the result and subtract $1$.  Look at this: `hist(rbeta(1e6, 3, 3)*2 - 1, freq=FALSE)` (about $0.2$ seconds).